# Facebook share not showing image from open graph metatags

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, meta-tags, social-media

I'm trying to integrate the Facebook share button to my employer's site, the title, url, description/intro are all displaying correctly, however no image is being attached.
When the share dialog opens, an image container flickers and then disappears as though facebook is trying to process the image(s) but fails.

I'm using og:image and a link relation to try and specify the image to use for shared links:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/images/logo_white_150px.png" />
<link rel="image_src" type="image/png" href="/images/logo_white_150px.png" />
```

That image used to work (it scaled appropriately) but no longer does, I've also tried other images of differing size and format with no luck.

Here's the open meta-tags I'm using in the header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
  <head>    
    <meta property="og:type" content="landing page" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Social Media Test Page" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="This is a page for testing the behavior of social media buttons..." />
    <meta property="og:image" content="/images/logo_white_150px.png" />
    <link rel="image_src" type="image/png" href="/images/logo_white_150px.png" />
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<%=shortUrl%>" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="site name" />
    <meta property="og:medium" content="mult" />
  </head>
```

Here's the JavaScript I'm using at the start of the body:

```
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
  ...
```

And here is how I'm using the button:

```
  <div class="left" style="text-align: center;">
    <a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="<%=shortUrl%>">Share</a>
    <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </div>
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance
Chris.

Comment: In my experience, the real problem is the cookies. Clear cache several times between your tests and it will work. Your code seems fine.

Comment: Fb has a free tool to test your site.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is OK on the scraped result, try to fetch new scrap information using [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

This is because Facebook use its own cache for og:data.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10796778)

Comment: @YPCrumble while that is usually right, it's not here. The link links to a tool. You cannot post a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the HTML output from your code, I could only make a guess as to the issue.
Don't use a relative url like `<%=shortUrl%>`, but be sure to use the fully-qualified Url....something that has the http(s):// on it.

Also, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/ says that this share button is being deprecated.  Please change over to using the Like button instead: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: I know the share button is deprecated, my employer still wants it until we can roll out a custom like button. the shortURL jsp variable is actually a fully qualified url that we compress using a Google library similar to tinyurl.

Comment: Maybe the image parser doesn't like redirects?  I've never tried.  But you can try removing the shorten url and placing the complete url in the OG tag instead.  Or for that matter, until you get it to work, hard code the og:image tag.

Comment: the og:image metatag uses the full path and I can access the image directly in the browser using that url

Comment: If the full, un-redirected url, is not able to be read by Facebook's linter, I'm unsure what to say.

Comment: Ah, I see that the content is getting scraped correctly now, I get a warning that the og:url tag should be explicitly specified (which it is?!) But apart from that it all looks good, the same behavior occurs though - the title, url, and description appear but not the image...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience :

- All the URLs should be absolute (even the og:image value)
- If your image is served equally over https you should add a og:image:secure_url meta property with absolute url as well (if you
  serve everything only over https you can skip this)
- Add as well a og:image:width and og:image:height meta properties

Main url redirection is very tricky, you should make absolutely sure your content is correctly (and fully) fetched, for complex dynamic content I often end up doing a detection in the .htaccess to serve FB’s crawler appropriate content as follow :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit/[0-9]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ OG_GENERATOR_SCRIPT_HERE.php [L,QSA]
```