# how to display title, description and image for facebook share widget

Tags: javascript, php

As I'm new to facebook apis, using facebook share widget in my website. It is working fine but now i want my share widget to post description and thumb image of specific video when user clicks on widget of video in my site. Currently it is posting fine with title, link(dynamic) and images(showing all images of that corresponding page). But i want to show only that particular thumb image of that video, all images instead. Please help me in this issue. I've gone through facebook meta tags og:'title',og:'description' and og:'image'. But none of them worked well..

here is the link of my site:

http://www.reportershub.com/profile/john_raj

Here is my code..

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">



<fb:share-button href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/tvnews/<?php echo $videos[0]['indexer']; ?>/<?php echo empty($videos[0]['title_seo']) ? $videos[0]['title'] : $videos[0]['title_seo']?>/success/videos/news" type="box_count"></fb:share-button>



<script>
                  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                    FB.init({
                      appId      : '',
                      //status     : true,
                      xfbml      : true
                    });`enter code here`
                  };

                  (function(d, s, id){
                     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
                </script>
```

Comment: First related stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814224/facebook-share-not-showing-image-from-open-graph-metatags?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `meta`, you can also use facebook sharer link -

`http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=titleheresexily&p[url]=http://www.mysexyurl.com&p[summary]=mysexysummaryhere&p[images][0]=http://www.urltoyoursexyimage.com`

Answer (score 0):

Open Graph (OG) are recommended and widely used across social networking site like Facebook, twitter, linkedin and list goes on ...

below is the code for Facebook OG meta

```
<!-- for Facebook -->          
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:url" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
```

Below link will help u further to debug the meta

<kbd>[Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)</kbd>

Example how to use OG tags,

<kbd>[Tutorial/Refernce](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/)</kbd>

About OG protocol

<kbd>[ABOUT OG](http://ogp.me/)</kbd>